# Apache crashes on installing Magento extension

Tags: php, magento

I am installing a Magento extenion on my Magento loacalhost.I get following error and xampp crashes.

```
    Problem signature:

  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH

  Application Name: httpd.exe

  Application Version:  2.2.21.0

  Application Timestamp:    4e6b3136

  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll

  Fault Module Version: 5.3.8.0

  Fault Module Timestamp:   4e537a04

  Exception Code:   c00000fd

  Exception Offset: 0018a7a3

  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

  Locale ID:    1033

  Additional Information 1: e339

  Additional Information 2: e339f2594e7f681a95b166793376bebb

  Additional Information 3: ad95

  Additional Information 4: ad95c11efe6aa075e55981fe5bf8d4b5
```

But if I disable the extension the xampp works well.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution on this link [APPCRASH php-error-faulting-module-name-php5ts](http://bd-programmers.blogspot.in/2013/11/appcrash-php-error-faulting-module-name.html)

Go to following file
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

Set Comment on following line.

```
#LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
#LoadModule php5_module "D:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
```

Uncomment the following line:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule actions_module>
    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
</IfModule>
```

If some one has any other good solution please share.